# Get objects of NSDictionary in to an array?

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary like :

```
{
levels =     {
    exchange =         {
        text = ALL;
    };
    product =         {
        text = ALL;
    };
    segment =         {
        text = ALL;
    };
    symbol =         {
        text = ALL;
    };
};
marginavailable =     {
    adhocmargin =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    branchadhoc =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    cashmarginavailable =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    collateralvalue =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    credits =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    directcollateralvalue =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    notionalcash =         {
        text = 0;
    };
    payinamount =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
};
marginutilised =     {
    adhocscripmargin =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    category =         {
        text = 0;
    };
    cncmarginused =         {
        text = 0;
    };
    cncsellcreditpresent =         {
        text = 0;
    };
    debits =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    elm =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    exposuremargin =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    grossexposurevalue =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    ipoamount =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    mfamount =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    multiplier =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    payoutamount =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    premiumpresent =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    realisedmtom =         {
        text = "-0.00";
    };
    scripbasketmargin =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    spanmargin =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    subtotal =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    turnover =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
    unrealisedmtom =         {
        text = "-0.00";
    };
    valueindelivery =         {
        text = "0.0";
    };
    varmargin =         {
        text = "0.00";
    };
};
net =     {
    text = "0.00";
};
```

}

Above dictionary contains four keys that is levels,marginavailable,marginutilised and net etc

I want objects from first three keys and last object in to an array.I have tried a lot but not finding out any logic to parse it.

I want array of dictionary like this

```
    exchange =         {
    text = ALL;
};
product =         {
    text = ALL;
};
segment =         {
    text = ALL;
};
symbol =         {
    text = ALL;
};
adhocmargin =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
branchadhoc =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
cashmarginavailable =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
collateralvalue =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
credits =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
directcollateralvalue =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
notionalcash =         {
    text = 0;
};
payinamount =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
adhocscripmargin =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
category =         {
    text = 0;
};
cncmarginused =         {
    text = 0;
};
cncsellcreditpresent =         {
    text = 0;
};
debits =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
elm =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
exposuremargin =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
grossexposurevalue =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
ipoamount =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
mfamount =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
multiplier =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
payoutamount =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
premiumpresent =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
realisedmtom =         {
    text = "-0.00";
};
scripbasketmargin =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
spanmargin =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
subtotal =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
turnover =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
unrealisedmtom =         {
    text = "-0.00";
};
valueindelivery =         {
    text = "0.0";
};
varmargin =         {
    text = "0.00";
};
net =     {
    text = "0.00";
};
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this dictionary contain dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addEntriesFromDictionary:` of `NSMutableDictionary` to build a new dictionary that merges each of the second-level dictionaries of your original data.

Something like this:

```
// Original data presumed held in origData

NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[newDict addEntriesFromDictionary: [origData objectForKey: @"levels"]];

// etc. for the other keys
```

Answer (score 0):

You just try following logic it may help you.

```
resultAry = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[resultAry addObject:[[parentDictionary objectForKey:@"levels"]objectForKey:@"exchange"]];
```

Like that you add all object from `levels` key then follow the same way for `marginavailable` and `marginutilised`

Then finally add `net`

```
[resultAry addObject:[parentDictionary objectForKey:@"net"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should hold good if the maindictionary contains dictionaries

```
 NSMutableArray *dictionaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSDictionary *childDictionaries in rootDict) { // rootDict is the original dictionary whic has all the four keys levels,marginAvailable,marginutilized and net

        for (NSDictionary *dict in childDictionaries) {
            [dictionaryArray addObject:dict];
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   [dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
     {
         if ([(NSString *)key isEqualToString:@"marginutilised"])
             *stop = YES;
         [newArray addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)obj];
     }];
```

Now you can got the result in newArray :)

Answer (score 0):

To get all objects in a array, you can also use enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: like so

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    [yourDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if([(NSString*)key isEqualToString:@"net"]){
            [yourArray addObject:[(NSDictionary*)obj objectForKey:@"net"]];
            *stop = YES;
        }
            [yourArray addObject:obj];
    }];
```